# Update-PnPApp to deploy SharePoint application to SharePoint Catalog

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I'm looking into deploying a SharePoint application to SharePoint Catalog using PnP PowerShell commands.

I was able to deploy the package to app catalog successfully. I’m now working on creating a script to automate the process of installing the solution on my site:

I created a script as follows:

```
   Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Tenant -Overwrite -Publish
   $packageInSite = Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Site -Overwrite -Publish
   Publish-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site         
   if ($packageInSite.InstalledVersion -eq $null) {
        Write-Verbose "Installing app..."
        Install-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site 
   }
  elseif ($packageInSite.CanUpgrade -eq $true) {
       Write-Verbose "Updating installed app..."
       Update-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site
   }
  else {
   throw 'Version ' + $packageInSite.AppCatalogVersion + ' already exists.'
  }
```

On running the above script, I see the following error:

```
Error:
{"odata.error":{"code":"-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The app for SharePoint with ID dd996c57-c36f-425a-8ede-bd77bfd24433 does not exist in the app catalog."}}}
At C:\Source...\Publish-PnPAppToAppCatalog.ps1:73 char:9
Update-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : WriteError: (:) [Update-PnPApp], Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Apps.UpdateApp
```

However, when I run the Get-PnpApp -Scope Site command, I do find the app present in the app site catalog.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I updated the code as follows:

```
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com" -Credentials $credential -TenantAdminUrl "https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com"
    Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Tenant -Overwrite -Publish
    
    Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites"

    $packageInSite = Add-PnPApp -Path $Path -Scope Site -Overwrite -Publish
    Publish-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site
   
    if ($packageInSite.InstalledVersion -eq $null) {
        Write-Verbose "Installing app..."
        Install-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site 
    } elseif ($packageInSite.CanUpgrade -eq $true) {
        Write-Verbose "Updating installed app..."
        Update-PnPApp -Identity $packageInSite.Id -Scope Site
    } else {
        throw 'Version ' + $packageInSite.AppCatalogVersion + ' already exists.'
    }
```

This gives an error:

```
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog : The list item could not be added or updated because duplicate values were found in the following field(s) in the list: [Site Collection Id].
At ###.ps1:55 char:5
+     Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site "https://<tenant>.sharep ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Admin.AddSiteCollectionAppCatalog
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to enable site collection App catalog：

```
Connect-PnPOnline (TenantSite URL)
Add-PnPSiteCollectionAppCatalog -Site (SiteCollection URL)
```

Here is a similar issue for your reference:

https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2611

Comment: Thank you! Should I add the above 2 commands before the first line of my code?

Comment: Also, could you please give an example of SiteCollection URL?